# Eclipse Juno and JBoss 6.1 configuration

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss6.x

This question has been asked before at least once in some form or another.
However the issue still remains. I've got Eclipse 4.2 Juno R2 and JBoss EAP 6.1
I want to configure JBoss in Eclipse. So I go to Window -> Preferences -> Server
-> Runtime Environment -> Add... -> JBoss -> JBoss v5.0

(note, there is no JBoss 6.1, the highest is 5.0 in the eclipse menu),

so I choose it, but then when I select /home/johndoe/jboss-eap-6.1 as the
installation directory the Next button still remains gray and I cannot
proceed.

Thanks.

Comment: i am in same scenario as you.i got it working but when i start server it gives me an exception and it wont start '12:13:18,327 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use: bind 127.0.0.1:9999'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The v5.0 support is probably looking for things very specific to 5.0  Try installing the JBoss Tools http://www.jboss.org/tools .

Comment: Thanks. I've installed JBoss Tools from Window -> Eclipse Marketplace... and now I can see two folders named JBoss Community and JBoss Enterprise Middleware in the Preferences' Servers tab Runtime Environments pane and I can add JBoss 6.1 EAP under JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6.1 Runtime (Tech Preview) (even though mine is not a preview but a full release from what I gather from the filename of what I downloaded). Anyways it accepts my download and lets me proceed.

Comment: i am in same scenario as you.i got it working but when i start server it gives me an exception and it wont start '12:13:18,327 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.remoting.server.management: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.remoting.server.management: JBAS017112: Address already in use: bind 127.0.0.1:9999'

Comment: Address already in use: bind 127.0.0.1:9999 means you already have something listening on that port on that address, like an installed copy of JBoss AS.